# web application using dash in python

Tags: dashboard, plotly-dash

I have develop a simple program using dash plotly in spyder but it showing me the following error.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div(
        html.H1(children='Hello Dash')
)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

but it showing me the following error.

```
Running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/
Debugger PIN: 870-923-677
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-13-3c5b23764cd8>", line 5, in <module>
    app.run_server(debug=True)

  File "C:\Users\Hussnain\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1503, in run_server
    self.server.run(port=port, debug=debug, **flask_run_options)

  File "C:\Users\Hussnain\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 938, in run
    cli.show_server_banner(self.env, self.debug, self.name, False)

  File "C:\Users\Hussnain\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 629, in show_server_banner
    click.echo(message)

  File "C:\Users\Hussnain\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\utils.py", line 259, in echo
    file.write(message)

UnsupportedOperation: not writable
```

Answer (score 0):

Spyder has some conflicts using `Debug=True`. Please run your code inside Visual Studio Code.

For my system: Your code is running fine.

Please tell us if this software swap solved your problem. If not, I will provide further assistance. :)