# Problem With Running Plotly Dash App on Google Chrome

Tags: plotly-dash

I'm trying to run a simple plotly dash tutorial. Whenever I run the code in spyder it works fine, but as soon as I copy this address http://127.0.0.1:8050/ and try to run it in Google Chrome, it never works. I have tried so many solutions but unsuccessful. I will appreciate your help.
This is my app.run_server code.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, host='127.0.0.1',port=8050)
```

I have tried to change it like debug=False, with or without host and port. But no vain.

Comment: Did the answer solve your query? If yes, could you please accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Found a couple of old answers on StackOverflow that might help you?

[Error Trying to initialize Dash in Spyder IPython Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49370550/error-trying-to-initialize-dash-in-spyder-ipython-console)

[web application using dash in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56202722/web-application-using-dash-in-python)

Basically it says that Spyder might have some issues rendering Dash. Have you tried alternate IDE's like Pycharm? My code runs effortlessly on pycharm.